# Custom PMD rules to address java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles and javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement issues in JDK1.5

Tags: xpath, pmd

java.lang.invoke.MethodHandls and javax.xml.bind.annoations.XmlElement are introduced in java7. When run the java application having these new features on JDK1.5 i am getting not resolved error. I have to write custom PMD rules to address these issues in JDK1.5. Therefore, Can anyone help me to write custom PMD rules.

Comment: Have you looked at https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.7.0/customizing/howtowritearule.html ? The PMD doc is quite useful. If you did, you should probably ask a more specific question about what you tried and your current issues.